# Delete operation using KnockoutJS and Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js

i'm having a problem with the delete operation using KOjs and EF6.when i click the remove button the confirmation dialog appears but the selected row is not deleted.
This is my controler:

```
 public JsonResult FetchActivities()
    {
        return Json(_account.FindAllActivities(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpDelete]
    public void DeleteActivity(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (id != 0)
            {
                _account.Delete(id);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

and this is the view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
<tr>
    <th>URL</th>
    <th>Thumbnail</th>
    <th>Title</th>
</tr>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Activities">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: urlactivite"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: thumbnail"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-bind="click: $parent.removeActivity">remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and here is the view model:

```
    var ProfilesViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var url = "/WhiteList/FetchActivities";
    var refresh = function () {
        $.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
            self.Activities(data);
        });
    };

    // Public data properties
    self.Activities = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.removeActivity = function (profile) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this profile?")) {
            var id = profile.id;
            waitingDialog({});
            $.ajax({
                type: 'DELETE', url: '/WhiteList/DeleteActivity/' + id,
                success: function () { self.Activities.remove(profile); },
                error: function (err) {
                    var error = JSON.parse(err.responseText);
                    $("<div></div>").html(error.Message).dialog({ modal: true, title: "Error", buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } } }).show();
                },
                complete: function () { closeWaitingDialog(); }
            });
        }
    };
    refresh();
};
ko.applyBindings(new ProfilesViewModel());
```

I see no errors in my code.Can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several mistakes:

1. the only observable property is the `Activities` observable array: when you load the data with `refresh()` you are creating an observable array of regular, non-observable, objects. That means that ypu are trying to make bindings between the regular, non-observable properties of your array and your activities.
2. you're not passing any parameter to your `removeActivity`, and you are expecting to get a profile (what is that) and get it's id to delete it.

You'd need to make modifications to your model:

1. Create an `Activity` constructor with the same properties of the activity, but declared as observable properties
2. One of these 2 options

   1. Include the `removeActivity` in the `Activity` constructor, to get the id of the activity to remove using `this` (or `self`)
   2. Include `removeActivity` in the root for your model, and recive the `id` as parameter, and pass the id of the activity in the click binding
3. Modify refresh so that you map each element of the received activities to a new `Activity` object created with your constructor

If you choose option 2.2 you can make it automatically using [knockout mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

Please, look at your code and try to see why you expected to receive a `profile` in `removeACtivity` function. I suppose you'll understand it made no sense.

Comment: Sorry ,Now i understand a little bit but this is my first expereience with ko and javascript.So please can you guide me to clear path and make it clearer.

Comment: I'm sorry man, but I'm not going to teach you KO. I've told you what's wrong with your code and the different options that are available to solve your problem. But, if you don't understand it, then you must complete the KO tutorials in the official page, and have a look at some other examples on the web. There are lots of it.  I'm not going to write working code for you, that would be useless. You'd rather learn the technology, and then ask for help.